# Android/Java - Passing long Value retrieved with getDate() to another Method

Tags: java, android, methods, long-integer

I have an OnDateChangeListener for my CalendarView which should get the selected date and save it as a long value.

```
CalendarView calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                CalendarView calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
                long selectedDate = calendar.getDate();}


        });
```

Then I have a Floating Action Button which should start another activity and pass the long value of the selected date, which the OnDateChangeListener got with an Intent to the next Activity.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                /*CalendarView calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
                long selectedDate = calendar.getDate();*/

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddEvent.class);
                intent.putExtra("selectedDate", selectedDate);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

The Value gets formatted and displayd in the next activity and saved into my realm database.

How do I make this long value accessible to all methods in this activity?

Comment: public static long selectedDate in your main activity

Comment: public static long selectedDate in your main activity

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variable 'selectedDate' global instead of locally in the method then every method of your activity can access it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a global variable like this:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{

    private Long mSelectedDate; 
    ...
```

Initialize it in your calendar change listener:

```
calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        CalendarView calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        mSelectedDate = calendar.getDate();
     }
});
```

And then, use it in your FAB:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddEvent.class);
        intent.putExtra("selectedDate", mSelectedDate );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, declaring the `CalendarView` twice is work that need not be done. You can simply declare the initial `CalendarView` as final and use it that way.

Alternatively, since this particular function actually gives you itself as a parameter in the function, you should just use that.

> public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int
>   month, int dayOfMonth) {

As for your actual question, you just need to make either your CalendarView or the long a [member variable of your class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).

Example:

```
class MyClass {
    // Member Variable
    private long mMemberVariable = 0l;

    // Constructor
    public MyClass() {
        foo();
        bar();
    }

    private void foo() {
        mMemberVariable = 1l;
    }

    private void bar() {
        System.out.println("Your variable is "+mMemberVariable);
    }
}
```